# NullInjectorError: No provider for FormBuilder

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-reactive-forms, angular-formbuilder

I need to use FormBuilder but the program gives me some error. This is a module that I can export from other component:

the module.ts is

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        FormsModule,
        DialogModule,
        ButtonModule,
        InputTextModule,
        TableModule,
        MessageModule

    ],
    declarations: [
        SearchCodeComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        SearchCodeComponent
    ],
    providers: []

})

export class SearchCodeModule { }
```

In my html i do:

```
  <form [formGroup]="descriptionForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
...
..
<input formControlName="code">..
```

In my ts I do:

```
 descriptionForm: FormGroup
```

The problem is that when I go on the page I obtain two exception

```
ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[FormBuilder -> FormBuilder -> FormBuilder]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for FormBuilder!
```

and other is:

```
 ASSERTION ERROR: Reached the max number of directives [Expected=> 4 != 4 <=Actual]
```

Anyone know how can I resolve this?

Comment: please add more information about your FormBuilder usage (DI, descriptionForm initialization)

Comment: any news on this? I'm facing the same issue on angular 9 and can't find a fix

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are importing `ReactiveFormsModule` in your `AppModule`. Remove it from your main `AppModule` import.

Check this thread on github, it contains some other possible ways to resolve this problem https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31221#issuecomment-617474627

Answer (score 0):

In your TS file you need to initialize your form group (as per NullInjectorError). One way is to initialize it inside `ngOnInit(){}` function. This gives you more control if you have more items in form.

```
ngOnInit(){
this.descriptionForm = new FormGroup({
    code: new FormControl('')
  });
};
```

or else you can do the following in TS file where you are declaring `descriptionForm`

```
descriptionForm: FormGroup  = new FormGroup({
        code: new FormControl('')
      });
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

add this in  component.modul.ts :

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

imports: [
ReactiveFormsModule

Comment: The answer can be improved with the usage of the formatting with ```.
Also, there is a typo in the file name, the “e” is missing from “module”.